# Curl Call to undefined function curl_init()

Tags: curl, php-5.5

I'm working on windows 10, I use in my php script cURL to get some resources:

```
<?php
// Get cURL resource
$curl = curl_init();
// Set some options - we are passing in a useragent too here
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'http://localhost/module/webservice.php/events/contentViewed/',
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'User Agent X'
));
// Send the request & save response to $resp
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
// Close request to clear up some resources
curl_close($curl);
print_r($resp);
?>
```

But I get this error:

> **Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init() in C:\wamp\www\testTracker.php on line 5**

I checked my php.ini file, the `extension=php_curl.dll` is enabled. In addition when I use `phpinfo()` to check if the cURL module is enabled I see only the authors of cURL = Sterling Hughes.

How can I fixe this error?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like cUrl is not installed. For e.g. if you're on a apt-based linux distro use:

```
apt-get install php5-curl
```